# Community, please review my question re-write on mortgages

Tags: discussion, new-users

[What can I plan for to save money on my mortgage?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/20797/what-can-i-plan-for-to-save-money-on-my-mortgage)

I reopened the question after getting the author's permission to help rewrite the question.  Please feel free to comment or edit away and make it better.

Also, I don't mean to override the community with the reopen, so if this question needs to go back to the closed status I will do it.

I mostly wanted to highlight KeithS's good answer.

Comment: Yes I agree with @Dheer -- I applaud your patience and efforts in rewriting!